# Find Connected Components Networkx

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, nodes, networkx

I need to find the connected nodes in the undirected and weighted graph. I did look up for some suggestions here but no one happens to answer that is related to my problem. These node pairs who also happen to connect with neighbors and every pair while connected spends some time in seconds connected.I am trying to find the connected components and the number of time the same comments connect and for how long (time) do they connect.

Eg:

```
Node  Node time
A      B    34
A      B    56
A      C    09
A      D    5464
A      C    456
C      B    36
C      A    345
B      C    346
```

So Over all `A B C` are connected two time

```
Nodes   connected  time
[A B C]    1       34+09+36 = 79
[A B C]    1       56+345+346 = 747
```

Expected output is

```
Nodes  connected  time 
[A B C]    2       826

And

Node  connected  time
[A B]   2         90
[B C]   2         382
[A C]   2         354
```

Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)
time = defaultdict(float)

data = np.loadtxt('USC_Test.txt')

for line in data:
    edge_list = [(line[0], line[1])]
    G= nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
    components = nx.connected_components(G)
    count['components'] += 1
    time['components'] += float(line[2])

print components, count['components'], time['components']
```

Input:

```
5454 5070 2755.0
5070 4391 2935.0
1158 305  1.0
5045 3140 48767.0
4921 3140 58405.0
5372 2684 460.0
1885 1158 351.0
1349 1174 6375.0
1980 1174 650.0
1980 1349 650.0
4821 2684 469.0
4821 937  459.0
2684 937  318.0
1980 606  390.0
1349 606  750.0
1174 606  750.0
5045 3545 8133.0
4921 3545 8133.0
3545 3140 8133.0
5045 4243 14863.0
4921 4243 14863.0
4243 3545 8013.0
4243 3140 14863.0
4821 4376 5471.0
4376 937  136.0
2613 968  435.0
5372 937  83.0
```

Wrong Output

The output i get is wrong

```
Last_node_pair  total_count_of_line  total_time  of Entire input data
```

Where as i am supposed to get

```
[5045 3140 4921]  [number_of_times_same_components_connected]   [total_time_components_connected]
```

Comment: Your code does not work: `edge_list = [(line_one[0], line_two[1])]` raises `IndexError: list index out of range`, could you edit your code so it works so we can suggest an answer

Comment: @EdChum Edited the code still has some error. Updated that too.

Comment: I think you need to do some more debugging and printing of values to understand the errors, to fix your first issue, change your line: `edge_list = line[0], line[1]` to `edge_list = [(line[0], line[1])]` the method `add_edges_from` accepsts a list of tuples.

Comment: In mean time i did try the same you happened to mention in previous comment. Now the error has changed to `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "topo_op.py", line 14, in <module>
    count[components] += 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
`

Comment: I get the same error, I think you should work through these errors, print off the values and lookup the api's to see what types they accept, at the moment there are too many errors to effetively answer your question but I think if you persevere you will get to your answer, when you get really stuck edit the question with your latest attempt and I will try to help. Good luck!

Comment: @EdChum I have changed the code and the output is wrong this case as given above.

Comment: Could you try this: `for line in data:
    edge_list = [(line[0], line[1])]
    G= nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
    components = nx.connected_components(G)
    #print (components)
    #print (line[2])
    count[components[0][0]] += 1
    time[components[0][0]] += float(line[2])

print(components)
print(count)
print(time)`

Comment: @EdChum But this gives me only the count and time of individual count and not the connected components.

Comment: try this: `for line in data:
    edge_list = [(line[0], line[1])]
    G= nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
    components = nx.connected_components(G)
    edge = str(components[0][0]), str(components[0][1])
    count[edge] += 1
    time[edge] += float(line[2])`

Comment: @EdChum  This gives me only the last node pair and the count of node pair occurring and the time they are connected `('937.0', '5372.0') 1 83.0` But not the connected components.

Comment: I think you need to try a little more to understand how to achieve what you want, at the moment it's not that constructive posting comments repeatedly which don't achieve what you desire.

Comment: @EdChum Sure i am working on trying different ways i shall edit code if i get any close to what i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. You're recreating the graph at each iteration, so you only ever have a single edge in your graph.
2. You're using the literal string "components" instead of the components variable as an index, so you're only saving and displaying that single value in your results dictionaries.
3. You're only printing the result once, at the end. There, the *components* variable happens to be the last component in the graph (it's the last thing assigned to that loop variable), and you're printing out your total component count and time, which is the total component count and time for *all* components because of Issue #2.

Here's something that should work. Out of laziness, I sweep through the data twice.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)
time = defaultdict(float)

data = np.loadtxt('USC_Test.txt')
G = nx.Graph()
for line in data:
    a,b,time = line
    G.add_edge(a, b)

results = defaultdict(lambda: list([0, 0.0]))
components = nx.connected_components(G)
component_map = { } 
component_stats = defaultdict(lambda: list([0,0.0]))
edge_stats = defaultdict(lambda: list([0,0.0]))
for nodes in components:
    for node in nodes:
        component_map[int(node)] = tuple(nodes)

for a,b,time in data:
    component_stats[component_map[a]][0] += 1
    component_stats[component_map[a]][1] += time

    if len(component_map[a]) > 2:
        edge_stats[(a,b)][0] += 1
        edge_stats[(a,b)][1] += time

for nodes,(count,time) in component_stats.iteritems():
    print sorted([ int(n) for n in nodes ]), count, time

print

for nodes,(count,time) in edge_stats.iteritems():
    print sorted([ int(n) for n in nodes ]), count, time
```

With your input, this produces the following output:

```
[606, 1174, 1349, 1980] 6 9565.0
[305, 1158, 1885] 2 352.0
[968, 2613] 1 435.0
[937, 2684, 4376, 4821, 5372] 7 7396.0
[4391, 5070, 5454] 2 5690.0
[3140, 3545, 4243, 4921, 5045] 9 184173.0

[1349, 1980] 1 650.0
[937, 4376] 1 136.0
[606, 1980] 1 390.0
[3140, 4921] 1 58405.0
[937, 5372] 1 83.0
[606, 1349] 1 750.0
[4391, 5070] 1 2935.0
[3545, 4921] 1 8133.0
[1158, 1885] 1 351.0
[3140, 3545] 1 8133.0
[2684, 4821] 1 469.0
[2684, 5372] 1 460.0
[937, 2684] 1 318.0
[1174, 1980] 1 650.0
[3140, 5045] 1 48767.0
[5070, 5454] 1 2755.0
[4376, 4821] 1 5471.0
[606, 1174] 1 750.0
[3545, 5045] 1 8133.0
[4243, 4921] 1 14863.0
[3140, 4243] 1 14863.0
[4243, 5045] 1 14863.0
[937, 4821] 1 459.0
[3545, 4243] 1 8013.0
[1174, 1349] 1 6375.0
[305, 1158] 1 1.0
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This looks correct to me but the output that i am looking is half correct. For Example `[606, 1980, 1349, 1174] 6 9565.0` is correct but i am also looking for something like this. `[606 1980]` \n `[606, 1349]` \n `[606, 1174]` with corresponding count and corresponding sum of time.

Comment: I see. So you want to track the components *and* the individual edges? I updated the answer to do this. Let me know if it's what you're looking for!

Comment: This looks perfect. I shall execute the code and accept the ans soon. Thank You so much :)

Comment: When I change to large input file i am getting the error. `G.add_edges_from((a, b) for a,b,time in data) ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Are you sure that "data" is a 3-column matrix? Maybe there's an extra space in your data file?

Comment: Yes the data is of 3 column

Comment: Very strange. I edited the answer a bit to make it easier for you to debug. Can you run it with a runtime that drops into a debugger on exception (i.e., `ipython --pdb script.py`) and, when it excepts out, do `print line`? That'll at least tell you what line it's failing on.

Comment: When run with small data file this works good. But when i have large data file this is not generating any output and the terminal is on hang for ages.

Comment: What's the size of the data we're talking about, here? Can you check where the analysis gets stuck (i.e., put in some debug print statements)?